# Python 3 - Check if finding index returns an error

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I'm trying to iterate through a code to basically create the find() function with patterns. I want to check if string[index + 1] returns an IndexError (slash if its out of bounds) in order to know whether to keep iterating through the string or to return the index of the first occurence. I've tried a couple different things, since it's in a class I created I keep getting an attribute error. Here are a couple things I have tried:

```
with self.assertRaises(IndexError):
                p[ind + 1]
                print(ind - len(p))
if not p[ind + 1]:
```

Comment: Try a `try` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `len()` function.

```
if 0 <= ind < len(p):
    ...  # p[ind] exist
```

`len()` returns length of string, greatest index in string is `len()-1` (because indexes are counted from `0`). You may also don't want to use negative index because it will get elements from end (for example, `'abc'[-1]` will return `'c'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it by either, `raises_error = (index + 1 >= len(p))` or `raises_error = (not p[index + 1:])`.  The first is, I believe, easily understood.  The second will check `p[index + 1:]` to see if it is empty.  The boolean value of an empty list is `False`.  This will happen if there is no such thing as `p[index + 1]`.  We then reverse it with `not`.